# Subclassed UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, subclassing

I want a subclass of UITableView that paints custom Section headers. I tryed as follows:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyTableView : UITableView
@end
@implementation MyTableView
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  //my drawing code goes here
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  //returns the height
}
@end
```

However when I use this class it draws the normal headers. What am I doing wrong?

When I Set those functions directly into a controller (without subclassing) it works fine.

UPDATE:
I already have many classes that use UITableView, I want to subclass it because it may be faster  to just change the class that writing the needed classes. How can I change the titles by just changing the class, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you inherited the `UITableView` class and this methods are not from `UITableView`, they are from the `UITableViewDelegate`.

It works on your controller because either you have set the `delegate` property of your `UITableView` pointing to your controller, or you are using a `UITableViewController`, which has the tableview delegate set automatically. (Actually, in your case, using a `UITableViewController` is worse because it already implements `UITableView` instead of your custom class).

EDIT: Unfortunately, due to the [delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) used in `UITableView` class to change its section header views, it is not straightforward to implement this kind of action

One way of doing that is providing these "helper" methods in your class, and then implement the delegate on each of your controllers to call these methods properly when the delegate method is fired.

If this approach is acceptable you should even consider using a category with these methods instead of subclassing you `UITableView`, which would make the code much cleaner.

Obviously you could set the `UITableView` delegate to be your custom class and then create another delegate for the calls you still want to be fired to the controller, such as `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and then call this new delegate methods as soon as the tableview fires the methods, but this is by far the worst possible solution

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are implementing `TableView` and not `MyTableView`:

```
@implementation MyTableView
```

*UPDATE:*

Check if you set correctly `dataSource` and `delegate` properties of that table.

*UPDATE2:*

You should subclass from `UITableViewController`:

```
@interface MyTableView : UITableViewController
@end
```

Comment: And it is still not working? Check properties `dataSource` and `delegate`

Comment: dataSource and delegate are set by the instance of the class. What must I check?

Comment: @Felipe Sabino says the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass UITableViewController, handling the viewForHeaderInSection and heightForHeaderInSection, then use MyTableViewController as the base class for each table view that you want to have your custom headers. However, viewForHeaderInSection is going to need to have the information necessary to create the UILabel or whatever you are going to use to display a header, so you are going to need some consistent code in your subclasses that will provide that - like an NSArray filled with the strings that you want for the headers, or a method that can be called from viewForHeaderInSection.